# PHP variable scope through a header:location redirect

Tags: php, variables

When redirecting using `header: location` how can I pass a variable along with this redirect?

For example, I have a value stored in `$username` in my function.

Part of the function:

```
if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

    // Sends an email
    send_email($email_address);

    // Reroute to success page
    $succeeded = true;
    header('Location: register-success.php');
}
```

Then on `register-success.php` I wish to output the username onto the page:

```
<?php 
echo $username;
?>
```

But when I do this I don't get an error, just a blank missing variable output where the `echo` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Just append it and send it..

```
if(register($email_address, $username, $password) === true){

    // Sends an email
    send_email($email_address);

    // Reroute to success page
    $succeeded = true;
    header("Location: register-success.php?username=$username"); //<--- Here
    exit; //<-- Add this too
}
```

and on your `register-success.php` page..

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['username'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a session variable. In your first script add

`session_start();` to the top of the page.

and to the top of every other page which needs to use a session variable.

you can then set things like `$_SESSION['username']`. These will be avaiable to every script in the same session, e.g. until the user closes their browser.

the benefit of this over using `$_GET` is that it's transparent to the browser, and therefore more secure.

If you want me to post more info about this (or anyone else for that matter), I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: I definitely agree using a session is better for security

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a GET request:

```
header('Location: register-success.php?username='.$username);
```

You can then retrieve the the variable using the superglobal `$_GET['username']`

ex. (in your register-success.php)

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
echo $username;
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `$username` or it will throw a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

I know, based on your other questions, that you're going session-crazy. So why not use sessions here? For example, I know that your register page uses `SESSION['status']['register']['error']` so why not use something like `SESSION['values']['username']` By doing it like this, you prevent somebody from pausing your request, switching the username and then displaying a different username and potentially (depending on how your code is structured) a different profile.

Then you just have to structure your register success page like such:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['values']['username'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. Is using sessions not recommended?

Comment: Using sessions is fine. They are more secure than cookies and they are definitely more secure than passing as a $_GET variable.